# date comparison in mongoosejs

Tags: mongoose

Comparing dates in mongoose seems to be failing for me.  My Date comparison always returns false even if I set the date to far in the future.

```
TaskSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    end: { type: Date, required: true, index:true}
})

task.end >= Date()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I exactly understand the answer but the following works if I new an instance of the Date instead of just calling Date()

```
task.end >= new Date()
```

I thought Date() was a static factory method that creates a date object, but I guess I could be wrong. If I console.log Date() and new Date(), they both print out dates, so not sure what the difference is, but regardless it works if I new the Date.